# Create variable in shared library for Jenkinsfile

Tags: environment-variables, jenkins-groovy

I'm new to shared libraries in Jenkins, and fairly new to Groovy as well.
I have several multibranch pipelines for different projects.  I have setup email notifications for each job using an environmental variable containing a list of email addresses, which works just fine.  However, several jobs share the same email addresses (depending on the project it's for) and I'd like to create a shared library for a master email list, so I don't have to update the list in each job individually if say I want to add or remove someone.  I'm having trouble defining a variable in a library that can be used later in the Jenkinsfile. This is a simplified version of what I've been trying:

**shared library** (basically a copy paste of the environmental variables I was originally using in the individual Jenkinsfiles/jobs, which works):

```
Jenkinsfile-shared-libraries\vars\masterEmailList

def call () {
   environment {
      project1EmailList = "user1@xyz.com, user2@xyz.com, user3@xyz.com"
      project2EmailList = "user2@xyz.com, user4@xyz.com, user5@xyz.com"
   }
}
```

***Jenkinsfile***

```
@Library('Jenkinsfile-shared-libraries') _
pipeline {
   agent any
   stages {
      stage ('email list for project 1') {
         steps {
            masterEmailList()
            echo env.project1EmailList
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The echo returns "null" rather than the email list of the project like I would expect.

Any guidance would be much appreciated!
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The "Defining global variables" section of https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-global-variables helped solve this one.

***shared library:***

```
Jenkinsfile-shared-libraries\vars\masterEmailList

def project1EmailList() {
   "user1@xyz.com, user2@xyz.com, user3@xyz.com"
}

def project2EmailList() {
   "user2@xyz.com, user4@xyz.com, user5@xyz.com"
}
```

***Jenkinsfile:***

```
@Library('Jenkinsfile-shared-libraries') _
pipeline {
   agent any
   stages {
      stage ('email list for project 1') {
         steps {
            script {
               echo masterEmailList.project1EmailList
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```